# Perturbations of planetary Orbits

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astronomy, astrophysics, astrometrics

I have, for years, been an Astronomy and physics nerd. For the first while, I was a total astronomy nerd. Then I slowly transitioned into physics and have been, for less than a year, a physics nerd. In this shirt while, I have taught my self calculus up to Calculus II (over summer and early this school year; I was 14 then). I know how to do geodesics, Schrodinger's equation, classical physics, etc and I'm teaching myself QFT and even planning to make one on quintessence. When I was an astronomy nerd, I didn't know how to do a lot of this math, and so I quit. Now, I am in an "astronomy comeback" phase. There's still one particular thing involving classical physics and astronomy that I still can't quite get-

The **question**- 
How exactly, with steps and math shown, do you derive the masses of asteroids via perturbations? *please*, no links, because I have searched and searched for years and can't find anything. Thank you!

P.s. An extra thank you if you read the whole thing(including the story)! 😄

Comment: Cross-posted from astronomy: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10247/

Comment: They wouldn't answer there. Very few questions are posted on ASE- but a question was posted a split second after I cross-posted this one.... Tells you the difference, huh!

Comment: I'm not aware that this is done. The planet Neptune was famously predicted based on its perturbations of the orbit of Uranus, but those are relatively isolated giant planets. The dominant perturbation on most of the objects in the asteroid belt is Jupiter. Do you have a source for the calculation you're trying to duplicate?

Comment: Any planet with any mass. Even pluto on other pluto now

Comment: Other plutinos Is what I meant,

Comment: Also, Saturn is a major force because of the v6 secular resonance, and it's own perturbations on Jupiter, which results in more non-constant Jovian perturbations? But Jupiter is still the main bully! 

Comment: The question said asteroids and asteroids

Comment: The phrasing here could be clearer - when you ask "how to derive the masses from perturbations", perturbations of *what* do you mean?

Comment: Asteroids perturbing asteroids gravitationally.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is originally from [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/dynamic-method-please-explain/18886#18886). Here is a [PDF file](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/reports/Hilton2002.pdf) from the [Astronomical Applications Department of the U.S. Naval Observatory](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/index.php). It explains how Asteroid masses and densities are calculated.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE and thank you for the contribution :) even though this link goes to another SE website, it would be nice if you would either add a short summary or quote (the relevant parts of) your answer here

Comment: What if I just copied my answer that is there to here?

Comment: as long as you leave the link, stating that this answer is originally from another SE I would be perfectly comfortable with that :)

Comment: That is a really interesting article! It contains a lot of excellent references and an overview. While it doesn't explicitly show how to do the math, I'd expect that would be quite involved, and probably done in several related but different ways, depending on the combination of orbits.

Comment: @uhoh: When I try to open the link, it's broken. Did you fix it somehow nontrivially?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Do you mean http://aa.usno.navy.mil/publications/reports/Hilton2002.pdf doesn't work for you? I've just tried it again and it still works fine for me. However I do notice from time to time "dot mil" things sometimes unpredictably take a while to load. The internet can occasionally become geopolitically messy perhaps :)

Comment: @uhoh: Yes, exactly this link and yes, it does time out on me, now repeatedly. Ah well, I'll have to try out a few locations on the globe then!